# iOS (objective-C) Popup

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup

I'm trying to create a pop-up in the initializer method of class FOO. I want the popup to appear and the init function to stop until the popup has been acted on by the user. If the user indicated continue FOO init will return an instance type. If not, the FOO init class will return nil;

What is the best data type/way to do this?

Comment: see https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller

Comment: "I want the popup to appear and the init function to stop until the popup has been acted on by the user" No, you really don't. Present the popup and decide whether to create a `FOO` afterwards. Don't put a view presentation inside an arbitrary class's `init`.

Comment: I'm not saying it's the prettiest or best way to do it, but it makes the most sense for the code base that Im working with. Is it still possible to do (acknowledging that it's not the ideal way to do things)?